# jQuery upgrade from 1.8.3 to 3.5.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-migrate

i know the following is written in the https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/ site.
but sadly it's confusing to me.

> Use the following steps to upgrade from a version of jQuery older than 1.11.0 or 2.1.0 to this new version 3.0

its saying older than 1.11.0, which doesn't apply to my current version of 1.8.. so should i use the `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js` or the `jquery-migrate-3.3.1.js` in my project?
Thanks!

Comment: found this link useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27971479/how-to-load-jquery-migrate-for-jquery-via-requirejs on how to use the jquery migrate plugin.
once the plugins have been added just run the server and on opening the pages errors can be seen:
`jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js:46 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated`

Comment: 1.8 is older than 1.11, so it seems like it *does* apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use both. First you update to v1.9+ using the jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable

the plugin will show you all that needs to be updated on the console when you load your app. The details of what these messages mean are here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/warnings.md

When there are no warnings left, then you can repeat this process with the plugin for v3.0:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#README

And the meaning of the different warnings is here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md